# public and private IP address of nodes on single computer kubernetes on coreos

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, coreos

While I am trying to generate and assign rsa keys to worker nodes from master node, one confusion I am having is what the assigned IPs should be or how I should configure network for each node(virtual machine) of kubernetes on CoreOS in single computer.

Currently when I am trying to get the master public / private IP(s) of each node, of course they all have single private IP and public IP.

Currently relying on Vagrant for creating and deploying the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant uses ignition plugin for CoreOS configuration.
You can take as a starting point [coreos-vagrant](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant) repository. In [this part](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L140-L143) of the Vagrantfile you can see the way IP addresses are assigned to nodes:

```
CLOUD_CONFIG_PATH = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "user-data")
IGNITION_CONFIG_PATH = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config.ign")
CONFIG = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config.rb")

# Defaults for config options defined in CONFIG
$num_instances = 1

# Attempt to apply the deprecated environment variable NUM_INSTANCES to
# $num_instances while allowing config.rb to override it
if ENV["NUM_INSTANCES"].to_i > 0 && ENV["NUM_INSTANCES"]
  $num_instances = ENV["NUM_INSTANCES"].to_i
end

<skipped>

(1..$num_instances).each do |i|
  <skipped>
    ip = "172.17.8.#{i+100}"
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip
     # This tells Ignition what the IP for eth1 (the host-only adapter) should be
    config.ignition.ip = ip
  <skipped>
end
```

The following articles tell you more about CoreOS setup using Vagrant:

- [Running CoreOS Container Linux on Vagrant](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html)
- [A CoreOS development cluster with Vagrant and VirtualBox](http://www.adaltas.com/en/2018/06/20/coreos-dev-cluster-virtualbox/)
- [Using Cloud-Config](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html)
- [How to Set Up CoreOS Environment](https://hub.packtpub.com/how-set-coreos-environment/)